# Using jScrollPane on a site. Wont scroll w/ scrollwheel. Whats wrong?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jscrollpane, expressionengine

site example: http://ec2-107-22-119-73.compute-1.amazonaws.com/index.php/info/databases

Working Example: http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/mwheel_intent.html

I cant get scrollwheel to work.

If you cant tell from the URL, my site is an expressionengine site. Using coldfusion and junk like that to build the pages.

anyone? (I tried searching for this issue, but no one seems to simply not be able to make scroll work.)

Comment: Before, it wasnt working. I hadnt named the files with .js because it didnt seem like they needed me to, which was dumb.

I just did fixed the naming. And it still wasnt working. So I posted here.

I just cleared the cache, and now it's all working. Thank you StackOverflow.

Comment: Message to all who see this: **Make sure you follow the instructions the developer gives you for his products**

and if you're using jscrollpane, your header's JS section should look like this: 

     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ec2-107-22-119-73.compute-1.amazonaws.com/index.php/script/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ec2-107-22-119-73.compute-1.amazonaws.com/index.php/script/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js"></script>

Comment: Since you solved the problem yourself, you should post your solution as an answer, and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the paths to your JavaScript/CSS files are named appropriately and aren't throwing 404 errors.

The easiest way to ensure valid links to your assets is to use the `{site_url}` [single global variable](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/templates/globals/single_variables.html#site-url) when linking assets in your templates:

```
<script src="{site_url}/script/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
<script src="{site_url}/script/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js"></script>
```

Which would result in the following:

```
<script src="http://example.com/script/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
<script src="http://example.com/script/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js"></script>
```

Since you're using ExpressionEngine's templates for your CSS — as opposed to flat files — you may want to give those template names a `.css` file extension.

So instead of:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/index.php?css=site/master.v.1324329515" />
```

You'd have:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/index.php?css=site/master.css.v.1324329515" />
```

This isn't absolutely necessary since EE will set the proper `text/css` MIME type [based on the template type](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/cp/design/templates/new_template.html#template-type). However, it does make reading and debugging the source code easier, and is more of a standard practice.

Understandably, many beginners reference and borrow code from the [Agile Records ExpressionEngine Theme](http://eeinsider.com/blog/new-in-2.0-agile-records/) that's available during new EE installations, so it's easy to recognize EllisLab's approach to markup and architecture — be it for the better or worse.

---

**Bonus:** remove the cache-busting timestamp (`v.1324329515`) in ExpressionEngine from CSS URLs, use the `{path}` variable instead of the `{stylesheet}` variable:

```
// With Cache-Busting String Appended
// http://example.com/index.php?css=site/master.css.v.1324329515"
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{stylesheet=site/master}" />

// Without Cache-Busting String
// http://example.com/index.php/site/master.css
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{path=site/master}" />
```